# unknown top level operator: $orderby

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, full-text-indexing

We've a [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) + [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) app running on [Ubuntu linux](https://www.ubuntu.com/) servers spun on [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) VPS.

One of our mongoose queries have a [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) with the following operators:

- [less than / equal to](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/)
- [limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830513/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-returned-items)
- [order by](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/orderby/)

and looks like this:

```
db.sampleCollection.find({
  $text: {
    $search: userInput
  },
  $lte: {
    expired: (new Date()).addDays(30)
  },
  $limit: 9,
  $orderby: {
    postedAt: -1
  }
})
```

which throws this error:

> unknown top level operator: $orderby

Solutions already considered:

- [Mongoose uses $set by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31620982/2404470), however we're not using that operator in our query
- [This solution considers aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26755603/2404470), however we need it for find function
- [This solution seems to be for array fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43681856/2404470), however we need solution for non-array indexes
- We're not mixing operators, [as said in this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33595614/2404470)

Need inputs on how to fix this.

Comment: @RolandStarke This query is not running on mongo shell anyways and ours is MongoDB server version: `3.4.3`

Comment: Did you try `$sort` instead of `$orderby` ?

Look this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825520

it might help you.

Comment: @PierreR-A Thanks for the inputs, will try to implement this soon and get back

Answer (score 3):

[Query modifiers](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-modifier/) like `$orderBy` are no longer supported:

> Starting in v3.2, the query “meta” operators are deprecated in the mongo shell. In the mongo shell, use the cursor methods instead.

As suggested by the docs, use the cursor methods like [`sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#cursor-sort) and `limit` instead:

```
db.sampleCollection.find({
  $text: {
    $search: userInput
  },
  $lte: {
    expired: (new Date()).addDays(30)
  }
})
.sort({
    postedAt: -1
})
.limit(9);
```

Comment: What about doing a query from javascript with the `mongodb` library?

Answer (score -1):

Check your mongodb version orderby has been deprecated since v3.2

```
$orderby Deprecated in the mongo Shell since v3.2
In the mongo shell,use cursor.sort() instead.
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/orderby/

```
db.sampleCollection.find({
    $text   : {
        $search: userInput
    },
    $lte    : {
        expired: (new Date()).addDays(30)
    },
    $limit  : 9,
    $sort: {
        postedAt: -1
    }
})
```